# pandas 0.14.1 installation linker error

Tags: python, pandas, installation, linker-errors, mingw32

When trying to install pandas with pip using python2.7 and mingc on windows 7 I run into a series of linker errors like:

```
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pandas\algos.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pandas\algos.def -LD:\Python27\libs -LD:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\pandas\algos.pyd
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pandas\algos.o:algos.c:(.text+0x2612): undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
```

pip downloaded version 0.14.1 of pandas.

What could be the problem here?

Christian

Answer (score 1):

For a much easier time, [download `pandas`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas) and its dependencies from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository. The site contains many many pre-compiled `.exe` installers for a whole range of scientific computing modules and related items, and is so much easier to use on Windows than trying to compile with `pip`. I'm not sure where exactly your current error is coming from, but there is the distinct possibility that you are missing a dependency somewhere.